# sql entity output log

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

I wanna to see entity output with SQL code. Cause I have no output.

```
using Proj_s.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    namespace mostlycode
    {
        public class ProjectContext : DbContext
        {
            public ProjectContext(DbContextOptions<ProjectContext> options) : base(options)    
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Worker> Workers{ get; set; }
           // public DbSet<ProjAssignment> ProjAssignments{ get; set; }
            protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().ToTable("Project");
                modelBuilder.Entity<Worker>().ToTable("Worker");
               // modelBuilder.Entity<ProjAssignment>().ToTable("ProjAssignment");
            }
        }    
    }
```

how to add code from here to mydbcontext
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx?
Here is simple but I do not know

Comment: you could just set `Database.Log` in the constructor?  Though of course you'd need to set it TO something.  Where do you want to see the output?  I'd recommend looking into a logging framework.  If you want to see the actual SQL being generated then I'd suggest using Profiler...

Comment: What is logging framework? How can I set it?

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed (from your USING statements in your code) that you seem to be using EF Core, so I assume this is actually a .Net CORE application?
Assuming it's .Net Core 2.0...
Follow this to set up NLog:
https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2

Then amend the NLog.config file - set the log file paths/names to whatever you wish,  and remove this line:

`<logger name="Microsoft.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="blackhole" final="true" />`

Then you should automatically get all the EF logging going to a log file.  EF Core uses the built-in .Net Core logging system, and this sets up NLog to do things with those log messages.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Assuming you're using .Net Core, then simply following the steps to hook this into the logging subsystem should be enough for EF to start logging stuff (though you'll need to make the changes to log "Microsoft.*" information somewhere.)  I had a minor issue with EF log entries polluting all my app's logfile - and I've never told EF explicitly to log anything.  I'm using .Net Core 2.0 and EF Core 2.0 for my app (Web Api)